# How to add a file to a table in MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, file, sql-server-2005

As the title, Now I have a table to save data, type of data is file. But I don't know how to do that.
Who can help me ?

I'm using C# (VS 2010, MS SQL Express 2005).

Thanks.

Comment: check blob type of column in sql.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917636.aspx

Comment: use varbinary. google it at least !!

Comment: @sgud what the hell are talking about ???

Comment: @sgud : I dont see this type in MS SQL ??? http://i206.photobucket.com/albums/bb108/voquanghoa/SQL.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file(s) in binary form in your C# code and store it in your table column with datatype `varbinary(MAX)`